# possible null reference argument for parameter 's' parse in 'double double.Parse(string s)'

Tags: c#

possible null reference argument for parameter 's' parse in 'double double.Parse(string s)'

```
dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
    i += 1;

    _total += double.Parse(s: dr["total"].ToString()); // warning message
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(i, dr["id"].ToString(), dr["transno"].ToString(), dr["pcode"].ToString(), dr["pdesc"].ToString(), dr["price"].ToString(), dr["qty"].ToString(), dr["disc"].ToString(), dr["total"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: `dr["total"]` can return `null`

Comment: First, you've failed to state any kind of question. Second, use Dapper so you don't have to grapple with extracting typed values from a reader, and doing it poorly.

Comment: what exactly is your question? The warning is pretty clear, IMHO. `dr["total"]` may return `null`, in which case you'd call `null.ToString()`, which eventually throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

C# does not know value of your column. That's why you are getting this warning. When the value of your column is null, calling `.ToString()` on null results in a `NullReferenceException` at runtime.

When you know that this column exists 100%, you can do it like this to get rid off the warning:

```
dr["total"]!.ToString()
```

Or even better: use an object-mapping framework like Dapper. It will save you tons of hours.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks! I've corrected it. You are right. This null warning comes from the value check of the column.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the warning is that `dr["total"]` *can* return `null` (in case there's no field `"total"` in the cursor) and `.ToString()` will throw exception.

If you are sure that the field does exist rain or shine you can switch this warning off with the [null forgiving operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) `!`:

```
  // using: do not forget to Dispose IDisposable (dr)
  using var dr = cm.ExecuteReader();

  while (dr.Read()) {
    i += 1;
    _total += Convert.ToDouble(dr["total"]!);

    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(i, 
      dr["id"]!.ToString(), 
      dr["transno"]!.ToString(), 
      dr["pcode"]!.ToString(), 
      dr["pdesc"]!.ToString(), 
      dr["price"]!.ToString(), 
      dr["qty"]!.ToString(), 
      dr["disc"]!.ToString(), 
      dr["total"]!.ToString());
  }
```

Note, that we can get rid of to and from `string` conversion and let .net convert the value with `Convert`